# How do I set a DependencyProperty which is being updated by a third party timer?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm playing around with the Vlc.DotNet library (Nuget: Vlc.Dotnet / https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) . It's effectively a WinForms wrapper around libvlc.dll, with a *very* cursory implementation of a WPF control which just wraps the WinForms control in a HwndHost:

```
//WPF control class
public class VlcControl : HwndHost 
{
    //The WPF control has a property called MediaPlayer,
    //which is an instance of Forms.VlcControl
    public Forms.VlcControl MediaPlayer { get; private set; }

    //WPF control constructor
    public VlcControl()
    {
        MediaPlayer = new Forms.VlcControl();
    }

    //BuildWindowCore and DestroyWindowCore methods omitted for brevity
}
```

This means that if I want to bind to anything I need to jump through some hoops. If my instance of the WPF control is called MyWpfControl, I need to address everything via MyWpfVlcControl.MediaPlayer.[SomeMethod/SomeProperty] . I'd like to add some DependencyProperties to the WPF control to make binding easier. I'm having issues with properties that update on a timer and are set by the backing dll, and by the user via the WPF control.

The WinForms player has a Time property of type long, indicating elapsed media time in milliseconds. It also has an event called TimeChanged which fires continually during playback, updating the elapsed media time.

I've added an event handler to my WPF control for the TimeChanged event:

```
//WPF control constructor
public VlcControl()
{
    MediaPlayer = new Forms.VlcControl();

    MediaPlayer.TimeChanged += OnTimeChangedInternal;
}

private void OnTimeChangedInternal(object sender, VlcMediaPlayerTimeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Time = e.NewTime;
}
```

If I set up a DependencyProperty in my WPF control to wrap around Time it looks like this:

```
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Time.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Time", typeof(long), typeof(VlcControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0L, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTimeChanged)));

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the Time property.
/// </summary>
public long Time
{
    get
    {
        return (long)this.GetValue(TimeProperty);
    }

    set
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            this.SetValue(TimeProperty, value);
        }));
    }
}

private static void OnTimeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    //Tried this - bad idea!       
    //MediaPlayer.Time = (long)e.NewValue;        
}
```

Time updates beautifully from libvlc.dll -> WinForms -> WPF. Unfortunately if I want to set the MediaPlayer.Time property from the WPF control I need to incorporate the commented line above in OnTimeChanged. When this is uncommented and MediaPlayer updates the Time property (as opposed to the WPF control), it gets itself into an infinite loop of TimeChanged -> SetTime -> TimeChanged -> SetTime -> ...

Is there a better way to implement this? Can I add a parameter somewhere that would indicate whether Time is being set from the WPF or WinForms code?

Comment: Just to clear something up VlcControl and Forms.VlcControl are different classes, right? Makes it kind of hard to read what is what.

Comment: Yes, VlcControl and Forms.VlcControl are different classes. I'll take a quick once-over through the question and see if I can clear things up a little.

Answer (score 1):

You might try implementing a type of indicator to prevent the infinite loop.   Something like:

```
bool isUpdating = false;
private static void OnTimeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!isUpdating)
    {
        isUpdating = true;
        MediaPlayer.Time = (long)e.NewValue;
        isUpdating = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give you still one roundtrip though I think. I ws thinking the same thing at first, too.

Comment: This is just about what I finished up with. I had to declare my indicator field as static to get it into scope for the static OnTimeChanged method.

Comment: In `OnTimeChanged` you have the object that raised the method (called `d` in the code above). So you can just cast it to `VlcControl` and use a public property on the control instead of a static flag.